# After Disable Rotation in ionic app, its rotating in LE2 android mobile

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

we are workinig on ionic 4 app, and disable landscape mode by writing

```
<preference name="Orientation" value="portrait" />
```

in config.xml but in LeEco Le 2 android mobile app is rotating.

Any idea about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Install both plugin**

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-screen-orientation
npm install @ionic-native/screen-orientation --save
```

> app.ts

```
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation/ngx';

constructor(private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {

  this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.LANDSCAPE);

}
```

for more information :
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/screen-orientation

Comment: thank you for help, but i already tried this, its not working